# How to handle dots in event names with @fires in jsdoc

Tags: javascript, doc, jsdoc

I have an event named `namespace.event`. The dots are causing issues in JsDoc when I want to use the tag  `@fires`. When I do:

```
/**
@fires MyClass#namespace.myevent
*/
```

The result I get is plain text `MyClass#namespace:event:myevent`. Is there any way to escape dots ?
I tried `namespace\.event` which doesn't work and `'namespace.event'` which keeps the dot, but renders with the quotes too.

For information, I found a workaround for the tag `@event` here: [How do you include a dot in names/events/callbacks with jsDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482496/how-do-you-include-a-dot-in-names-events-callbacks-with-jsdoc). But this does not apply to `@fires`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very bottom it says to quote the name with the special characters.  So it should be `MyClass#"namespace.myevent"`

http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html

Comment: The frustration here is that I have a namespace with a dot like this: ko.dt. When I surround it in double quotes, I get the ko.dt string displayed but it also displays the literal double quotes.

Comment: @DavidHyogo That sounds frustrating - did they fix that yet?

Comment: @tastybytes that links is broken for me.

Answer (score -1):

Running into the same problem. The solution that works for me was to use a dot-like character (ONE DOT LEADER unicode:U+2024). I copied it from char overview window.

for mac:
system settings -> keyboard -> show overview in panel

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work for. It just displayed a literal :U+2024